# Parent call to Control.DrawToBitmap does not seem to respect clipping region set in child control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have created a UserControl which simply defines a new GraphicsPath and sets that to be the Region of the control. Its primary use is to act as a backdrop for other controls so typically the only thing set on it is BackColor. When I call DrawToBitmap on the control's parent, the child control is drawn as a rectangle rather than getting clipped to region I expected. Am I missing something here?

Standard use of the control does not exhibit this problem.

Also, I need to be able to draw this control to an image while it is not currently shown on screen. I have seen some workarounds would *could* have worked had I not had this additional requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by 'draw this control... while it's not currently shown on screen'?

Answer (score 0):

DrawToBitmap does not honor regions.  But [Graphics.CopyFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DRAWING.GRAPHICS.COPYFROMSCREEN%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) does.

```
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location, new Point(0, 0), this.Size);
        }
```